# Can't Call Payable Function from Web3

Tags: web3js, erc-721, payable, solidity-0.8.x

I am trying to call a `public payable` function from my smart contract (^0.8.0) in a ropsten testnet

```
    function purchaseCardPack() public payable {
        require(msg.value == cardPackFee, "VALUE SENT NOT EQUAL TO CARD FEE");
        _createCardPack();
    }
```

using `web3.js`

```
  const buyCardPack = async () => {
    try {
      await NFTContract.methods.purchaseCardPack().send({from: account, value: web3.utils.toWei('0.015', 'ether')});
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
```

and for some reason seeing the error "Transaction Error. Exception thrown in contract code." in MetaMask before I can even send the transaction.

Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong or if there is any other information I can give. Thanks in advance!
[image: This is the error I am seeing]

Comment: It might be that `_createCardPack` is causing an error.

Comment: You were right! I was dividing by 0 (an array with length of 0 to be specific) in a function elsewhere in the contract I that _createCardPack was using. Removing this and replacing with a different uint fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with `_createCardPack()`. I was dividing by 0 (an array of length 0, specifically) in a function that it was referencing. Replacing that with a uint did the trick for me.

*Takeaway* There was nothing wrong with the payable setup, it was an error upstream in the contract. Hope this helps others :)